# using triggers for ensuring data consistency

Tags: java, oracle, triggers, consistency

I have a hierarchical structure stored in a table. Each element has a pointer to its previous, next and a parent

```
create table CATALOGUE
(
  NAME VARCHAR2(300) not null,
  NEXT_ID NUMBER(38),
  PARENT_ID NUMBER(38),
  PREVIOUS_ID NUMBER(38),
  XID NUMBER(38)
);
```

I have a java application, which uses O/R mapping to access and modify this table. Sometimes my catalog got corrupted, e.g. they are linked elements which don't have the same parent. I'm wondering if I can ensure data consistency using Oracle triggers or other pure SQL technique (without java code).

Is this "the correct way" of doing things?

How can I implement a trigger? I can implement a stored procedure which would validate my table. Something like

```
select count(*) 
from catalogue c1, catalogue c2 
where c1.next_id = c2.previous_id and c1.parent_id != c2.parent_id
```

should return 0.

But how can I call it on commit? I don't want to call it on every row update, just before the commit is finished with a possibility to rollback if my table is not valid.

Comment: "they are linked elements which don't have the same parent"  How could a trigger ever determine what the "same parent" might mean?

Comment: @S.Lott: I added some info to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible to enforce this by a combination of a materialized view (MV) and a constraint on the MV as I have described [here in my blog](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/enforcing-complex-constraints-in.html).

The idea would be to create an MV that held only exceptions to the rule, and then to have a constraint that always fails when a row is entered into the MV.  Something like this:

```
create materialized view check_mv
refresh complete on commit as
select 1 dummy
from catalogue c1, catalogue c2 
where c1.next_id = c2.previous_id and c1.parent_id != c2.parent_id

alter table check_mv
add constraint check_mv_chk
check (1=0) deferrable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should write a package that is 100% in control of maintaining this table. If necessary, put it in it's own schema, lock down privileges on it, and use ONLY THIS PACKAGE to modify the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  As I explained before, I have a java application. More precisely, a buggy java application. I want to use pure SQL to avoid inconsistency in the DB. But I don't want to switch the implementation of my business logic from java to SQL.

Comment: I would offer the same advice, just in java form - have one java class that handles the maintenance of this table. It's harder to enforce using it, but for something this critical, you need centralized control. Otherwise you're going to be hunting bugs in perpetuity. I don't know what your activity level is in the application, but other solutions are going to involve additional overhead. Good luck, and +1 for an interesting question...