# What options are available for applying a set level constraint in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have a situation where I need to ensure that there is only one active record with the same object_id and user_id at any time. Here is a representative table:

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    object_id integer,
    user_id integer,
    active boolean default true,
    created_at timestamptz default now()
);
```

By only one active record at a time, I mean you could have a sequence of inserts like the following:

```
insert into actions (object_id, user_id, active) values (1, 1, true);
insert into actions (object_id, user_id, active) values (1, 1, false);
```

but doing a subsequent

```
insert into actions (object_id, user_id, active) values (1, 1, true);
```

should fail because at this point in time, there already exists 1 active tuple with object_id = 1 and user_id = 1.

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150677/using-triggers-for-ensuring-data-consistency) which looks interesting, but its Oracle specific.

I also saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663263/sql-using-trigger-for-constraint) but it requires more care regarding the transaction isolation level. I don't think it would work as-is in read committed mode.

My question is what other options are available to unsure this kind of constraint?

Edit: Removed the third insert in the first set. I think it was confusing the example. I also added the created_at time stamp to help with the context. To reiterate, there can be multiple (object_id, user_id, false) tuples, but only one (object_id, user_id, true) tuple.

Update: I accepted Craig's answer, but for others who may stumble upon something similar, here is another possible (though suboptimal) solution.

```
CREATE TABLE action_consistency (
    object_id integer,
    user_id integer,
    count integer default 0,
    primary key (object_id, user_id),
    check (count >= 0 AND count <= 1)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION keep_action_consistency()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN

    IF NEW.active THEN
        UPDATE action_consistency
        SET count = count + 1
        WHERE object_id = NEW.object_id AND
        user_id   = NEW.user_id;

        INSERT INTO action_consistency (object_id, user_id, count)
        SELECT NEW.object_id, NEW.user_id, 1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM action_consistency
                          WHERE object_id = NEW.object_id AND
                                user_id   = NEW.user_id);
    ELSE
        -- assuming insert will be active for simplicity
        UPDATE action_consistency
        SET count = count - 1
        WHERE object_id = NEW.object_id AND
        user_id   = NEW.user_id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;

    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ensure_action_consistency AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON actions
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE keep_action_consistency();
```

It requires the use of a tracking table. For what I hope are obvious reasons, this is not at all desirable. It means that you have an additional row each distinct (object_id, user_id) in actions.

Another reason why I accepted @Craig Ringer's answer is that there are foreign key references to actions.id in other tables that are also rendered inactive when a given action tuple changes state. This why the history table is less ideal in this scenario. Thank you for the comments and answers.

Comment: The boolean flag only complicates things. For a N<-->M relation table, the row either exists, or it does not. No need to flag it as "do not use".

Comment: Wrt your update (added "created_at" timestamp): add a separate history table.

Comment: @wildplasser the boolean flag is more complicated. In the application its a bitmask. I used the boolean flag here to try and simplify things to illustrate the problem. A history table would work. That would allow me to maintain the UNIQUE constraint on the actions table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your specification that you want to limit only one entry to being `active` at a time, try:

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    object_id integer,
    user_id integer,
    active boolean default true,
    created_at timestamptz default now()
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX actions_unique_active_y ON actions(object_id,user_id) WHERE (active = 't');
```

This is a *partial unique index*, a PostgreSQL specific feature - see [partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html). It constrains the set such that only one `(object_id,user_id)` tuple may exist where `active` is `true`.

While that strictly answers your question as you explained further in comments, I think [wildplasser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12360571/398670) describes the more correct choice and best approach.

Comment: Thanks Craig! I think this is the best solution given the constraints. I agree that @wildplasser's is probably the best approach, but given the application feature are working within the simplest and most straight forward solution is to ensure there is only one active action row per object, per user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UNIQUE constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2016) to ensure that the column contains the unique value...
Here, set of `object_id` and `user_id` have been made unique....

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    object_id integer,
    user_id integer,
    active boolean default true,
    UNIQUE (object_id , user_id )

);
```

Check Out **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/42301)**

Similary, if you want to make set of `object_id`,`user_id`  and `active` as `UNIQUE`, you can simply add the column name in the list of `UNIQUE`.

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    object_id integer,
    user_id integer,
    active boolean default true,
    UNIQUE (object_id , user_id,active )

);
```

Check Out **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/58e09)**

Comment: This would cause the second insert to fail. See the example I included. The context here is that you may be able to insert one record, later set the active field to false then insert another with the active set to true.

Comment: Do you want to  set of object_id,user_id,active as unique in each row?

Comment: No, object_id, user_id, active need not be unique but, there can only be one tuple (object_id, user_id, active) where active is true. As a result, a UNIQUE constraint on (object_id, user_id, active) will not work. The data needs to retain history about the records previously deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

Original:

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    object_id integer,
    user_id integer,
    active boolean default true
);
```

my version:

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    object_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES objects (id),
    user_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, object_id)
);
```

What are the differences:

- omitted the surrogate key. It is useless, it enforces no constraint, and nobody will ever reference it
- added a (composite) primary key, which happens to be the *logical* key
- changed the two fields to NOT NULL, and made them into foreign keys (what would be the *meaning* of a row that would *not* exist in the users or objects table?
- removed the boolean flag. What is the semantic difference between a {user_id,object_id} tuple that does not exist versus one that does exist but has it's "active" flag set to false? Why create three states when you only need two?

Comment: sorry, my original post was not as clear as it could be. I made some clarifying changes that should illustrate why your answer would not be satisfy what I'm looking for.

Comment: History is the key. Your boolean flag would move into the history table (INSERTED vs DELETED), and the timestamp could also go there. The foreign keys could be nullable (in the history table) and probably stop acting as foreign keys (if you cannot guarantee the user_id and object_id to be stable over time, and don't want to screw your history)